# Vim-like keyboard input in all text fields in all programs

Tags: vim, universe

So, I'm addicted to vim and often add lots of garbage to regular text fields when I try to use vim commands and am not in vim. I thought to myself, why can't vim be EVERYWHERE?!

Then it struck me. Why not? Has anyone written a program that could redirect input/current text fields into a vim buffer so that one could use vim-style editing in things other than terminals and gVim? Redirect keyboard input? Alter a key-logger?

Any thougts as to how it could be done?<strike>$wdw thoughtsA</strike> I did it again. I need serious help. Ideas, anyone?

UPDATE: More in need. I just got an email with this as the tail end of it:

> Campus librarians will be happy to
>   work with faculty and students to
>   identify  alternative high-quality
>   sources of scientific news reporting
>   and analysis.
>
> --Karen 
>   :r signature

Its nice to know there are others.

Comment: You need a `:s/\$wdw /^wce/`.^[:wq

Comment: @intuited english?

Comment: Hmm looks like I was correcting @physicsmichael 's strikeout-ed text that was meant to fix the typo in the word "thoughts [sic]".  For more explanation, fire up `vim` and do `:help :s`.

Answer (score 2):

I use [`vi`-style editing in `bash`](http://www.catonmat.net/blog/bash-vi-editing-mode-cheat-sheet/) and [vimperator](http://vimperator.org/) for web browsing with firefox (sadly doesn't have `:vsplit`). In firefox the fantastic [It's All Text!](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/4125) plugin configured to use `gvim` makes input boxes (likes this one) less crappy. `mutt` picks up my `$EDITOR` without problems (tell Karen to set that variable, too).

I guess that's all I ever do outside of `vim`.

Comment: I'll be checking vimperator for possible chrome extensions regularly. If I used Firefox, this would be awesome. It's a great start; thanks a lot!

Comment: I followed some vimperator forums to vrome for chrome. I haven't gotten it to work, but for the sake of others there is an option.

Comment: You can also try `uzbl` for a similar feel, but it needs a lot of work to get the features one is used to from "normal" browsers.

Answer (score 1):

I've not seen anything to allow this, but it sounds like it could be handled by writing a module to plug into an IM such as [SCIM](http://www.scim-im.org/) or [IBus](http://code.google.com/p/ibus/).

Answer (score 1):

This isn't exactly what you are looking for, but I also have experienced the desire for vim keybindings everywhere. One solution I've used is [Touch Cursor](http://touchcursor.sourceforge.net/), which I mapped so that my home row keys would allow me to navigated my cursor. The default arrangement is not vim-like, but you can easily change that. It may take some getting used to holding the space bar to achieve chords, but I found it pretty natural.

These are some other programs that offer application-specific solutions: I use [Viemu](http://www.viemu.com/), which provides a vim emulation layer in Visual Studio 2005/2008, Outlook and Word.

There is also a new chrome extension that adds vim-like keybindings for browsing as well called [Vimium](http://vimium.github.com/).

Answer (score 1):

I haven't found a way yet, but using an `xclip` script you can at least make the copy-paste-edit-paste cycle speedy. It pastes into a temporary file and edits it with Vim:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

# Dependencies: xclip, gvim

# Create an "ephemeral" file, that disappears with this process
tmpfile=$(mktemp /tmp/vim-edit-clipboard.XXXXXX)
exec 3>"$tmpfile"
rm $tmpfile

# It's unlinked, but can be referred to by other processes using /proc
ephemeral_path=/proc/$$/fd/3

# Paste to the file
xclip -selection clipboard -o > $ephemeral_path
# Edit it. Make Vim respect the presence or lack of EOL at EOF
gvim --nofork -c 'set nofixeol' $ephemeral_path
# Then copy it to the clipboard, removing the newline at the end
xclip -selection clipboard < $ephemeral_path
```

You'll probably want to assign a keyboard shortcut to this script, so you can do something like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>, <kbd>Super</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>

Comment: if you want to get rid of the extra <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>a</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>c</kbd> before each time you can simulate the inputs at the start of your script with something like [xdotool](https://github.com/jordansissel/xdotool): `xdotool key --clearmodifiers ctrl+a key --clearmodifiers ctrl+c`